# ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/

Tags: angular, angular-cli

good morning, I have created my project and now I want to output with the ng build --prad command, but I have encountered an error. How can I fix this error?
I guess the problem is from the following code, but I do not know how to fix it

```
    "budgets": [
         {
         "type": "initial",
         "maximumWarning": "2mb",
         "maximumError": "5mb"
         },
         {
         "type": "anyComponentStyle",
         "maximumWarning": "6kb",
         "maximumError": "10kb"
         }
    ]
```

error in terminal:

```
ng build --prod

    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/layout-dialog/dialog-successful/dialog-successful.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 17.4 kB with a total of 23.4 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/login/login.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 201 kB with a total
    of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/about-me/about-me.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/header-admin/header-admin.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by
    201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/show-documents/show-documents.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met
    by 201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/show-expertise/show-expertise.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met
    by 204 kB with a total of 210 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/show-records/show-records.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 200 kB with a total of 206 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/contact-me/contact-me.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 202 kB with a total of 208 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/about-me-admin/about-me-admin.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was
    not met by 201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/documents-admin/documents-admin.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/expertise-admin/expertise-admin.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 204 kB with a total of 210 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/messages-admin/messages-admin.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was
    not met by 200 kB with a total of 206 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/records-admin/records-admin.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/home.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 225 kB with a total of 231 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/records-admin/ae-record/ae-record.component.scss. Budget 6 kB
    was not met by 201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/documents-admin/ae-documents/ae-documents.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 200 kB with a total of 206 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/about-me-admin/edit-about-me-admin/edit-about-me-admin.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/expertise-admin/ae-expertise/ae-expertise.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 201 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    
    WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/layout-dialog/dialog-delete/dialog-delete.component.scss. Budget 6 kB was not met by 224 kB with a total of 230 kB.
    
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/layout-dialog/dialog-successful/dialog-successful.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 13.4 kB with a total of 23.4 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/login/login.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/about-me/about-me.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/header-admin/header-admin.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/show-documents/show-documents.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/show-expertise/show-expertise.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 200 kB with a total of 210 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/show-records/show-records.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 196 kB with a total of 206 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/contact-me/contact-me.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 198 kB with a total of 208 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/about-me-admin/about-me-admin.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/documents-admin/documents-admin.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/expertise-admin/expertise-admin.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 200 kB with a total of 210 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/messages-admin/messages-admin.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 196 kB with a total of 206 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/records-admin/records-admin.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/home/home.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 221 kB with a total of
    231 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/records-admin/ae-record/ae-record.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/documents-admin/ae-documents/ae-documents.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 196 kB with a total of 206 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/about-me-admin/edit-about-me-admin/edit-about-me-admin.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/expertise-admin/ae-expertise/ae-expertise.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 197 kB with a total of 207 kB.
    ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for E:/project/PwpEnd/PWP/src/app/layout/admin/layout/layout-dialog/dialog-delete/dialog-delete.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 220 kB with a total of 230 kB.
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "PWP": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/PWP",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "PWP:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "PWP:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "PWP:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "PWP:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "PWP:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "PWP",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "c792c032-9136-42b5-8b0a-391b6f8d84c5"
  }
}
```

pakege.json:

```
{
  "name": "pwp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

app.routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ValidTokenRoutingGuard } from './valid-token-routing/valid-token-routing-guard';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./layout/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  { path: 'Admin', canActivate: [ValidTokenRoutingGuard], loadChildren: () => import('./layout/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) },
  { path: 'Login', loadChildren: () => import('./layout/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Just... increase the budgets..?

Answer (score 15):

It is a compiler error so you notice that your files are below the defined size.
Just modify the configuration in angular.json and increase the `maximumError` size properties to suit your needs and build again.
I would also recommend to check your project in order to remove any unused code or dependencies so that the size is reduced .

Comment: Thanks, my problem was solved and I did this to load the site faster for the first time.
But it still leads slowly for the first time.
What to do?

Comment: You should use lazy loading in your Angular app so only the required modules are loaded at the start and the rest of feature modules are loaded when you navigate to its routes. This is a must when having a big application to reduce chunk size and initial load times - check this documentation: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: If you are talking only about the compilation, modern Angular uses an incremental compiler so that first time you build the app it takes longer and after that it goes faster.

Comment: As you can see, I used lazy loading, but it still loads late

Comment: Check the size of your chunks in dist folder and also that only the required chunks are loaded when opening the app in the browser (Network Tab).

Comment: Also, if you are starting your application with dev server, make sure you user ng serve --prod to optimize it.

Comment: Yes, it is used correctly, but it still loads slowly because Angular is powerful.
How much should I increase the maximums?

Comment: I have a quite big application and our budget config is:
             "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "15mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
For any regular app the defaults set by Angular when creating the app with ng cli should be enough until it grows big.
As you say, Angular is not the most lightweight framwork.

Comment: Anyway, this does not affect to loading time in the browser, it only sets the warnings and error while building the app.
If your app loads slowly you have to check your logic, performance, browser, computer, etc. Use the Chrome Dev Tools.
My application starts in 2-3 seconds in Angular 10 and its very big.
For lightweight apps I would recommend other framework, to be honest.